# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89 Current browser version is 91.0.4472.77

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, version, driver

Getting the error while running the script.
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89
Current browser version is 91.0.4472.77

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `ChromeDriver` is outdated.

The latest stable release(ChromeDriver) is `ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24`

Latest beta release: `ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.19`

Get it from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with selenium using python then I would recommend a python package `webdriver-manager`. You can install it using pip : `pip install webdriver-manager` 
Once the package is installed, you won't need to specify the chromedriver path or download `chromdriver.exe`
 Just use the below lines in your script and the plugin will identify the version of chrome browser installed in your system:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("google.com")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach did not work for [my issue with getting the latest version of chromedriver automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279326/undetected-chromedriver-requires-newer-chromedriver-version-than-automatically).

Comment: What is your current version of Chrome browser? Are you specifically looking for an older version?

Comment: No, as you can see in my post, the latest version required is not installed by the package, but rather the 2nd latest.