# undetected_chromedriver requires newer chromedriver - version than automatically provided

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Before instantiating a new [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) - instance, I ensure that the latest [ChromeDriver version](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) is installed via the [python-chromedriver-autoinstaller](https://github.com/yeongbin-jo/python-chromedriver-autoinstaller) library as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72123590/12298276):

```
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

'C:\\Users\\username\\project_path\\lib\\site-packages\\chromedriver_autoinstaller\\106\\chromedriver.exe'
```

As can be seen, it automatically installs version **106**, but in the error message (caused by the intent to instantiate the undetected Chrome Driver via `UndetectedChromeDriver.Chrome(options=self._browser_options)`), it states I need the next version **107**:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:... from session not created:
> This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version **107** Current
> browser version is **106**.0.5249.119

Another conventional way of automatically installing the required chromedriver did not work either:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import undetected_chromedriver as UndetectedChromeDriver

return UndetectedChromeDriver.Chrome(
    options=self._browser_options,
    service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

I need to deploy this remotely, so there should be a way to automatically get and install the required ChromeDriver - version.

The full error message with traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\project_path\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 103, in __init__
    def __init__(
  File "C:\Users\username\project_path\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 35, in __init__
    def __init__(self, executable_path=DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE_PATH, port=DEFAULT_PORT,
  File "C:\Users\username\project_path\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 37, in __init__
    def __init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix,
  File "C:\Users\username\project_path\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 195, in __init__
    def __init__(self, command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444',
  File "C:\Users\username\project_path\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 599, in start_session
    def start_session(self, capabilities=None, browser_profile=None):
  File "C:\Users\username\project_path\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in start_session
    def start_session(self, capabilities: dict, browser_profile=None) -> None:
  File "C:\Users\username\project_path\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 408, in execute
    def execute(self, driver_command: str, params: dict = None) -> dict:
  File "C:\Users\username\project_path\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 102, in check_response
    def check_response(self, response: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:...
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 107
Current browser version is 106.0.5249.119

Stacktrace:

Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00FEACD3+2075859]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F7EE61+1633889]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E7B7BD+571325]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E9DFCD+712653]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E96D24+683300]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E96B01+682753]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ECDBD3+908243]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ECD6AA+906922]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EC7136+880950]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E9FEFD+720637]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EA0F3F+724799]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0129EED2+2769538]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01290D95+2711877]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0107A03A+521194]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01078DA0+516432]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F8682C+1665068]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F8B128+1683752]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F8B215+1683989]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F96484+1729668]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x774CFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779E7BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779E7B8E+238]
```

**EDIT** (more info about Chrome Version):

```
C:\Users\username>REG QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon /v Version

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon
    Version    REG_SZ    106.0.5249.119
```

Comment: What does "reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Google\\Chrome\\BLBeacon /v version" return?

Comment: @misantroop it returnes the following:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon
    Version    REG_SZ    106.0.5249.119`

Comment: Multiple locations for ChromeDriver possibly? Cannot reproduce it here.

Comment: Alright, what is the easiest way to look for multiple locatons (i.e. where and how)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same issue just yesterday !

after spending some time looking for solutions, I found [this thread](https://patchmypc.com/forum/index.php?topic=1015.0) from 2016 suggesting that google chrome doesn't change its version in the registry when it auto-updates. It would explain why KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon is of an older version than your current browser one.

This is obviously quite annoying as `chromedriver_autoinstaller` uses this exact value in order to determine the current browser version, thus creating this error.

I haven't found any solutions in order to solve this exact issue but managed to find another way to automatically download the latest correct chrome driver using the `webdriver_manager` library (which essentially does the same as `chromedriver_autoinstaller` but with some additional features such as the possibility to give it an exact chrome driver version) ! It uses [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880917/how-to-get-chrome-version-using-command-prompt-in-windows) that manages to get the proper current browser version using the command prompt. The downside of it is that it requires a hard coded path to the browser executable :

```
import re
import subprocess

chrome_version = subprocess.check_output(
    r'wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" get Version /value',
    shell=True
    )
    
# Retrieve the current browser major version
chrome_version = re.sub('Version=', '', chrome_version.decode('utf-8').strip()).split('.')[0]
```

Once the version is retrieved, we can manually find out its associated chrome driver version thanks to the Google API and then instantiate a `ChromeDriverManager` with it (inspired by how `webdriver_manager` internally works) :

```
import urllib
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

latest_release_url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE"

latest_release_url_version = f"{latest_release_url}_{chrome_version}"

with urllib.request.urlopen(latest_release_url_version) as response:
    chrome_driver_version = response.read().decode("utf-8")

chromedriver_filepath = ChromeDriverManager(version=chrome_driver_version).install()
```

I hope this error will be fixed one day as this workaround doesn't look very robust, but it seems doing the job. Also, I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/464) on `webdriver_manager`'s GitHub repository and might do the same with `chromedriver_autoinstaller`.

Hope it helps !